# Proof on Infinite Limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

If the function $f$ is defined by

$f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational

$f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Can someone help me answer this question step by step so I would know how to prove a question like this next time? Thank you.

Comment: This is called the *Dirichlet function*. It is also the *characteristic function* of the irrationals.

Comment: Actually, I had that backwards. The Dirichlet function is 1 on the rationals and 0 on the irrationals.

Comment: This function is $[x\notin\Bbb Q]$, using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $0$ and $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $0$.

Then look at the sequence of functions for each sequence.

Answer (score 5):

An equivalent approach to Yunus's is to go to the definition. Suppose the limit exists and is $L$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there would exist a $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. But no matter how small $\delta$ is ,there are both rationals and irrationals that are less than it. So some values of $f(x)$ will be $0$ and others will be $1$. If $\epsilon < 0.5$, then there is no value of $L$ that will work for every $x$ less than $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x=a,$

$\bf{L.H.L(Left\; hand \; limit) = } \lim_{x\rightarrow a^{-1}f(x)} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a-h) = 0$ or $1$

(as $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a-h)$ can be rational or irrational.)

Similarly $\bf{R.H.L(Right\; hand \; limit) = } \lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+1}f(x)} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a+h) = 0$ or $1$

Hence $f(x)$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$ as for all values of $a$

So $\bf{L.H.L(Left\; hand \; limit)}$ and $\bf{R.H.L(Right\; hand \; limit)  }$ does not exists